# Unable to get my stylesheet to work (atom/html)

Tags: html, css

I am starting to learn HTML, CSS etc by following a project video. I am using Atom and have followed the video step by step but for some reason Atom does not seem to want to recognise my stylesheet. It isn't altering anything.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is what you've posted above what's actually in your file, or are you showing your HTML and styles in one gob? Please see [ask] and revise to clarify.

Comment: Hi. Above is my index & style sheet. For some reason it has put it together! Apologies. 

When typing the post it did display as 2 different code boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a dot before in the href like

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />`

Comment: Poor code formatting obscured this in the original post.